# Different image sizes as inputs for Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, image-annotations

When using Tensorflow 2 object detection api when do I normalize images of different sizes. Do I preprocess all the images to be same size then annotate with object bounding box? Or do the models somehow do the resizing internally and adjusts the predicted bounding box? The pre-trained models seems to have a preset sizes.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/models
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection
https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to my understanding, it is not required to normalize or all the images do not need to be resized by yourself. API will do the job, all you need to do annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).